# String datetime into spark sql

Tags: pyspark

How do we convert this date time string `2018-02-07 00:45` into sparksql timestamp..tried 
`to_timestamp('2018-02-07 00:45', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')`
and
`date_format('2018-02-07 00:45', 'y-MM-dd hh:mm').cast(TimestampType()`

both did not work.

This is in pyspark..

Comment: Please provide the code you tried, it helps

Comment: here is the code...`process_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                                                                                      
  sql_qry0 = " SELECT  status, url, resource_id, identified,                     (cast(unix_timestamp('"+process_time+"','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as timestamp)) as etl_time 
                    from events_data_tbl"`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

(sc
    .parallelize([Row(dt='2016_08_21 11_31_08')])
    .toDF()
    .withColumn("parsed", to_timestamp("dt", "yyyy_MM_dd hh_mm_ss"))
    .show(1, False))
```